# Romanian Special Characters Ș, Ț, Î

Tags: html, utf-8

How do i make 'ț' or 'ă' letters to be the same size like the rest? It looks like it's bold.
I am using bootstrap and the html code is like this

```
<h2 class="hs-line-2 mb-60 mb-xs-30 wow fadeInUpShort" data-wow-delay=".2s">Centrul Multifuncţional de Pregătire </h2>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the regular font you are using for your text does not include the Romanian characters. Browsers usually try to substitute those missing characters by using characters from similar fonts than the one you originally specified. In your case, this substitution font appears to have a higher weight than your regular font.

In any case, to fully solve this, make sure that you are using a font which includes all characters you aim to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your characters are not so special, but it seems that the font do not support such characters (either pre-composed, or just by including the standard character and an accent). So often the layout tools will choose a different font. In your case, it seems that it includes a font which has more "weight".

Because you included a `html` tag, I assume you want to create a page with such characters. The best way it is to use webfonts: so that the browser of that page will download automatically the font, without need to install on reader systems. In this site you have many information how to use webfonts (usually just few lines in CSS). Google Fonts provides a list of many webfonts. In addition it provide you the code, if you want to uses them from Google server (so without downloading on your webserver).